# VBA Current Line Arrow in Margin Cannot be Moved suddenly

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbe

I have been using the vbeditor for many years but suddenly I can no longer "drag & drop" the current line execution arrow like before. I can't interact with it at all. I can't pull it up or down. Instead of an arrow when I hover over it my cursor turns into a dot with 4 triangles at the cardinal directions, like a compass. All my settings are correct per previous posts on other forums, but still an issue. My colleagues are having the same issue as well. And I reinstalled excel after restarting my machine. And I dont think excel has had any updates in the last month (Jul'23) when this issue first appeared. Please help, thank you.

[image]

Comment: In the VBE, go to Tools, Options, in the Editor tab, is 'Drag-and-Drop Text Editing' checked? If not, check it, close the dialog and try again to move the execution point arrow.

Comment: Hi There, thank you for responding. Yes it is checked, all settings appear normal. Nothing has changed in the past 2 weeks since I last was using the editor. So this is very bizarre.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: 1. Have you tried moving the execution point from a different line? In fact, tried to do so in a different VBA project entirely to see if it is something specific to the line/proc/module/project?; 2. Not a solution but, to test, can you move the execution point using the keyboard and/or menu instead of drag/drop (ie while stepping through code, put cursor into the line to move the execution point to, then either press Ctrl+F9 or Debug > Set Next Statement?)

Comment: hi John, I haven't tried that test specifically yet, so I will give that a try today. Theres a slight work around where you can copy and paste the section to return to a previous line thats not ideal but workable for the time being. I and my colleagues are on a Mac if that makes any difference. You said you tried it on your end on a windows and there was no issue? Im not familiar with the 'set next statement' functionality but my main issue is navigating to previous lines of code, does the 'Set Next Statement' allow me to go to previous lines also? TYVM for your assistance in this matter.

Comment: Yes, Set Next Statement (in the Debug menu in the VBE's main menu) will let you go forwards or backwards and will be a lot simpler than copy/pasting code I reckon ... assuming Mac functionality is the same as for Windows

Comment: Hi John, yes now that I am using the 'set next statement' this totally solves my problem. It's actually easier! Thank you so much!